# How to get rid of the SolidDocuments spyware?

Tags: internet-explorer, spyware

I just installed the latest version of PDFCreator and made sure that the option of installing the PDFCreator and Yahoo default Search are NOT installed, but for some reason whenever I start Internet Explorer, I get this annoying warning from my firewall:

> Internet Explorer (IEXPLORE.EXE) is trying to connect to
>   www.soliddocuments.com (216.74.55.182) using remote port 80 (HTT -
>   World Wide Web). Do you want to allow this program to access the
>   network?

[image]

I do not wish this spyware to call home whenever I start Internet Explorer, so of course I answer "No". But that blocks IE from accessing any website... How do I get rid of this SolidDocuments spyware without uninstalling PDFCreator?

I tried `Internet Options > Advanced > Restore Defaults` but that didn't help. Also, the Home page is set to `Use Blank`. So this spyware must be hiding somewhere else.

Any idea where? How to get rid of it?

Comment: Any spyware has absolutely no business being on your computer whatsoever.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a firewall that was discontinued in 2005? And judging from the Yahoo toolbar, you didn't download the real PDFCreator installer.

Comment: Did you get PDFCreator from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/ ?

Comment: this is the most current looking info about the STUFF and possible ways to turn it off. http://www.pdfforge.org/forum/open-discussion/6172-problems-setup-pdfcreator-110  It has changed many times, sooo, cant even be sure of that.

Comment: @Lionel Yup. That's exactly where I downloaded it from.

Comment: @digitxp Because it works better than any current firewall I have evaluated so far. As you can see in this case. ;)